# How to get information about load time of each control on the page?

Tags: asp.net

I have an web page and different nodes in it. Nodes are configured using SiteMap/SiteMapNode. Each node is referenced as an aspx file. Each ASP.NET page holds one or more custom controls.
I have to add a control in the main page that displays information about how each control in currently displaying node has taken.
Any pointers on how I can do the same? 
Also, please let me know what other information do I need to provide to help guiding me. So, please free to ask the same.
Also node that each control on a page has different operations - like one can make a db operation while the other can make call to some service, while the other is performing some AJAX operation.

Comment: Have you tried using the performance/profiling/timeline module in F12 browser tools? press F12. Depending on your browser you'll get different options to allow you to see the timing of all the elements in your page and what they were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try using tracing  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972204.aspx to

custom control it's just a page is it has a load event create stop watch and start in the load page event when the logic code done just stop the watch something like that :

```
   using System.Diagnostics;
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        watch.Start();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        watch.Stop();
        Response.Write(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: I considered this option. As I understand, tracing spews lots of information. This is not helpful to me because of the following reasons:  1. I am only total load time and that to be displayed at a particular location on the page, possible in a control.  2. I am also interested in load time provided by controls after they perform operations to display data - like querying db etc.